# loop through parent li using jquery

Tags: jquery

hi all I have a menu sturcture with children and children built using ul li ul li etc, im trying using the following code to loop through just the root level li's and add a class to the children ul, however, its looping / counting the children of the first element so instead of there being 5 root li's there are about 40
var x = 0;

```
$('#BodyContent_FocusActivityMenu1_LeftNavFocus ul li').each(function () {
    if (x > 4) {
         alert(x);
          $(this).children('ul').addClass('toLong');
    }
    x++;
});
```

can anyone tell me where im going wrong

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do

```
$('#BodyContent_FocusActivityMenu1_LeftNavFocus > ul > li').each(function () {
   ....
```

But instead of your loop, if you want to add a class to the ul that are children of li elements with index greater than 4, you might do

```
$('#BodyContent_FocusActivityMenu1_LeftNavFocus > ul > li:gt(4) > ul')
    .addClass('toLong');
```

Comment: hi thanks for that ill try it, I did start of using gt(4) but thought it wasnt working so thats when I started trying with the .each()

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of your goal. If there is still a problem, try putting your html structure in a fiddle or in the question, so that it will be clearer.